# Reassigning value of iterator while iterating through it

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iteration

> First of all **a disclaimer**:
>
> I don't want to use a code like this, I am aware it is a bad practice. As well I am not interested in tips on how to improve it, to make it right. What interests me is a theory.

How come code like this works in python 3.6:

```
ls = range(5)
for elem_a in ls:

    ls = range(5, 10)
    for elem_b in ls:
        print(elem_a, elem_b)
```

I am reassigning the value of ls while iterating through it. Is the value of `ls` in the first iteration stored in memory during the first execution of `for elem_a in ls`?

Comment: For the outer loop, `ls` is already `range(5)` beforehand and it just iterates through this iterable no matter it changes inside the loop.

Comment: Great, I thought so. Thank you, for the immediate answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reassigning the variable you're looping over has no effect because the variable isn't re-evaluated for every iteration. In fact, the loop internally loops over an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), not over your `range` object.

Basically if you have a loop like this:

```
seq = range(5)
for elem in seq:
    seq = something_else
```

Python rewrites it to something like this:

```
seq = range(5)

loop_iter = iter(seq)  # obtain an iterator
while True:
    try:
        elem = next(loop_iter)  # get the next element from the iterator
    except StopIteration:
        break  # the iterator is exhausted, end the loop

    # execute the loop body
    seq = something_else
```

The crucial aspect of this is that the loop has its own reference to `iter(seq)` stored in `loop_iter`, so naturally reassigning `seq` has no effect on the loop.

All of this is explained in the [compound statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> ```
> for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
>               ["else" ":" suite]
> ```
>
> The expression list is evaluated once; it should yield an iterable
>   object. An iterator is created for the result of the `expression_list`.
>   The suite is then executed once for each item provided by the
>   iterator, in the order returned by the iterator.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and in-depth explanation. Much appreciate it.